# Steps for installing JRE to users' pc manually

Tags: java, c, jar

I am currently working on a jar file and I am going to distribute it soon. I was looking forward to distributing it for user without him needing installing JRE to run my app. I am well aware of tools like [Jar2Exe](http://www.jar2exe.com/) but those tools inject some additional content to the executable and I am not going to buy license for that! So I am working on a solution. And I have the idea, So I will create a C file with this content ( I am using C Language power in nativity! ) :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("java -jar test.jar");
    return 0;
}
```

And I will put the jar file and the compiled file of the C file above and java.exe located in my JRE installation dir in a same directory and this should work but surely there are a bunch of dlls that `java.exe` depends on them! A list of those dependencies to put them all in a directory and make the idea work will be very helpful:)

**Please Note** : I don't want to create an executable from the JAR file, I only want the user need not **INSTALL** JRE.

**EDIT**

---

I realized the above approach isn't practical, so I am going to install JRE behind the scenes ( my only goal is that the user doesn't find out whats going on in the installation process ) I am going to copy required files to `ProgramFiles/jre_version` but what in addition should I do? In the other words what does the JRE installer do under the hood?

Comment: Executing a java application is not possible without a jre.

Comment: Does java.exe + bunch of dlls very differs from normal JRE?

Comment: JRE is a *runtime environment* as the name suggests. It is the environment the java program is running in. It can't run outside of it.

Comment: You can grab a portable JRE here http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable and you could run this without an install.

Comment: And of course it won't work without standard java classes, which should be distributed too.

Comment: Requiring a JRE be installed would be the more practical approach - could I ask for clarification as to why you don't want to require this? Is it for ease of use, or something else?

Comment: @ N.J.Dawson, Just don't want to get the user mixed in these ...

Comment: You need to investigate Java Web Start.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think those other companies want you to pay money for their product?

Hint: because it ain't that easy.

The point is that not only need **your** JAR file. You need to make each and any class that your code will be using available to the JVM you are starting up.

You know, exactly that other stuff that those commercial tools are **backing** into their EXE files; the stuff that you think makes their EXE files so big and slow. That is the stuff that you need to run your java classes ...

The JRE alone comes with megabytes and megabytes of java classes, packaged up in various JARs. And any 3rd party library that you are using will be required too.

So, of course, when you are able to find **all** classes that will be loaded when your code is executed, then you could manually package that into a single JAR. But as said: if that would be an easy undertaking, those other people wouldn't have much of a business case. And of course: as soon as reflection and `Class.forName()` kicks in, you are completely broken. Because you can't predict at all, which classes will be used at runtime then.